# How can I generate different random numbers for each player?

Tags: c, random, srand

Both players get the same random number! ّI want each player to get a different number since they are throwing dice. 
here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int roll_a_dice(void);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{   
    int flag;
    int answer1 = roll_a_dice();
    int answer2 = roll_a_dice();

    printf("Die 1 (rolled by player 1): %d\n", answer1);
    printf("Die 2 (rolled by player 2): %d\n", answer2);

    if (answer1>answer2) {
        printf("Player 1 is starting!\n");
        flag = 1;
    } else {
        printf("Player 2 is starting!\n");
        flag = 2;
    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");

    return 0;        
}

int roll_a_dice(void)
{
    int r;

    srand(time(NULL));
    r = 1 + rand() % 6;

    return r;
}
```

The players are throwing dice. So number has to be 1-6.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Put the different options 1..6 in an array. Select a random array index. Remove that item from the array (by swapping it with the last in the array and shortening its length).

Comment: move `srand ( time(NULL) );` outside the roll_a_dice

Comment: Another gross multi-dup

Comment: Ah so I misread the question. OP does not want different random numbers, he wants random numbers that are not the same.

Comment: RTFM: Use `srand()` once, and only once.

Comment: Looking for a better dupe .... re-opened, but certainly a dupe

Answer (score 5):

`srand ( time(NULL) );` is used to seed the pseudo-random number generator. `time()` having a granularity of 1 second, if you seed the PNRG every time you call the `roll_a_dice()` function, for all the calls made within the granularity period, `rand()` will end up returning the same *random* number.

Move the `srand ( time(NULL) );` out of the `roll_a_dice()` function, call that only once in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Sorry if this was a noobie question I'm very new into coding and I'm trying my hardest.

Comment: Why didn't you flag this as one of the thousand duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+srand+ ?

Comment: He can still get the same dice roll for each player.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well yes, but only by chance, instead of every time.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to seed once.
Move srand to the top of main and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`srand( int );` is used to **initialize a seed**.
From there each time you call `rand()` you'll
get a new random value. By calling `srand()` in `roll_a_dice()`
you keep reseting the seed every time. Just move `srand()`
at the start of your main().